# Dividing multiple column by other column in csv python

Tags: python, csv, normalization

I have a dataset in my csv file. In the csv file, I would like to divide certain columns by other columns and keep certain columns unchanged. For example, csv file includes data with header named as:

col1 , col2 , col3, col4, col5, col6, col7

I want to have an outcome as:

col 1, col2, col3/col5, col4/col5, col5/col5, col6/col5, col7/col5, col3/col7, col4/col7, col5/col7, col6/col7, col7/col7.

If you notice, col1 and col2 is kept unchanged. the rest of columns are divided by col5 and col7.

What would be the simplest way to do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the csv in pandas and create a new column with that logic

First load the file into pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Then create each column based on the logic you described

```
df['NewColumnA'] = (df['col3']/df['col5'])
```

And so on.

Then you can save the new dataframe to a new file

```
df.to_csv('new.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks this is a smart way. 

How would I be able to save them all in a difffrent csv file?

Comment: you can use `df.to_csv('new.csv')` I added this to my answer. If I have answered your question please make sure to vote and/or close the question.

Comment: Thanks. very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would create a more generalized example for you:

Creating an example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,7), columns=["Col"+str(x+1) for x in range(7)])
```

dividing every column, other than the first two, by column 5 and renaming the columns:

```
div_col_5 = df.iloc[:, 2:].div(df["Col5"], axis=0)
div_col_5.columns = div_col_5.columns + "/Div5"
```

same for column 7:

```
div_col_7 = df.iloc[:, 2:].div(df["Col7"], axis=0)
div_col_7.columns = div_col_7.columns + "/Div7"
```

and concatenate:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:2], div_col_5, div_col_7], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Out[411]: 
       Col1      Col2  Col3/Div5  ...  Col5/Div7  Col6/Div7  Col7/Div7
0  0.314491  0.696337   1.005950  ...   0.323949   0.932692        1.0
1  0.545377  0.180576   1.399902  ...   9.506195   3.635226        1.0
2  0.420602  0.467427   3.437187  ...   1.177838   2.524279        1.0
3  0.011387  0.914098   0.908774  ...   1.184980   0.015985        1.0
4  0.313922  0.060917   0.699330  ...   2.525486   1.114208        1.0
5  0.862102  0.905982   0.329856  ...   1.854076   1.715368        1.0
6  0.275227  0.956603   0.479383  ...   0.700991   1.016879        1.0
7  0.181315  0.254490   0.770150  ...  40.635818  12.386609        1.0
8  0.733485  0.906282   0.590301  ...   1.054039   0.362268        1.0
9  0.096279  0.227469   0.040561  ...   0.844232   0.851515        1.0
```

Comment: How can I modify this code to divide columns to spicify which columns to be divided by col7 and col5 rather than all the columns except 1,2. For example if I didnt want to divide column 1,2,4 and 6. in your code (which is great!) you start dividing from column 3... what if in the between there are some columns that I dont want to divide?